# Ubuntu Dubai Date & Time Settings

Tags: time, date

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and I reside in Dubai and thus I set up my date and time settings accordingly. However, I do not speak Arabic but Ubuntu insists on displaying the date in Arabic. Other applications such as Skype on my Ubuntu machine display date and time in Arabic. Is there anyway I can change this to English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with time and date settings; it's because your computer's language is set to Arabic. In order to display time and date in English, for instance, you'll have to change your computer's language to English.

**Changing Current System Language:**

You can do that by going to `System Settings`, then click `Language Support`. If English (or your preferred language) is not installed, you can do so by clicking on `Install/Remove Languages`.

**Changing Regional Format**

Click Language Support again, but this time change to Regional Format and select English (or your preferred format); press Apply System-wide.

Comment: But the rest of my system is displayed on english. Its only the date that's displayed in Arabic.

Comment: Then go again to Language Support, but this time change to Regional Format and select English; press Apply System-wide. (I'll add this to my current answer)

Comment: is there any way I may delete this question seeing as it is a duplicate?

Comment: Is there no "delete" option in your post? Seems weird, although it is not necessary, you may as well delete it without problem